# Перестал запускаться сайт с Tomcat после подключения Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, jsp, tomcat

Разбираюсь с Hibernate и Tomcat, сделала пробную страницу сайта, навесила несколько сервлетов, запуск с Tomcat прошел норм, на запросы сервлеты реагировали. Потом решила добавить БД и подключила Hibernate, и теперь при запуске по адресу localhost:8080 Tomcat выдает ошибку 404, хотя раньше без проблем заходил на index.html сразу, сервлеты тоже не отвечают. Почему так может быть? Вот ссылка https://github.com/Mircella/plaisir_site , может что-то с версиями не так? Спасибо всем за отклики=)

Comment: Я вот что подумала, я до этого запускала также веб ресурс, но там еще при все этом участвовал Spring MVC, и тогда все запустилось. Это не может быть с этим связано?

Comment: Попробовала запустить приложение, но без использования RequestDispatcher, просто с PrinWriter, чтобы проверить, что сервлеты работают - они отвечают, но если прошу показать jsp файлы, пишут, что resource is not available(

Comment: Директорию с ресурсами перемещали?

Comment: @lampa нет, по этой директории раньше requestDispatcher видел jsp, а теперь нет

Answer (score 0):

Нашла в чем ошибка - в Project Structure почему-то при подключении Hibernate, а впоследствии и Spring меняется путь в Web Resource Directory - не знаю с чем это связано, но после того как указала правильную директорию, все снова запустилось и сервлеты заработали. Но буду рада, если кто-нибудь объяснит, почему адрес сам меняется при подключении фреймворков?